# Перемножение списка из перемноженных списков

Tags: python, python-3.6

Если создать матрицу n на n из нулей путём умножения списков

```
n = 3
a = [[0]*n]*n
```

А потом приравнять первый элемент главной диагонали 1, то весь первый столбец будет состоять из 1. Почему?

```
a[0][0] = 1
print(a) #[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Я так понимаю это из-за того, что при умножении мы просто создали несколько ссылок на один список. Но если умножить список только один раз, то таких проблем нет. Почему?

```
n = 3
a = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
a[0][0] = 1
print(a) #[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: `a` это _не_ список из `n` _копий_ `[0]*n`, каждый элемент `a` указывает на один и тот же список. В случае с `[0]*n` это нормально - `0` иммутабельный элемент, его можно только _заменить_ а не _изменить_, а вот список списков - другое дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основные нюансы которые нужно знать, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос:

1. Умножение списка на целое число, создаёт более длинный список, в котором несколько раз повторяются ТЕ ЖЕ САМЫЕ ОБЪЕКТЫ, которые были в исходном списке.
2. Использование конструкции вида `[выражение for i in iterator]` на каждой итерации заново вычисляет выражения и список будет состоять ИЗ РАЗНЫХ ОБЪЕКТОВ, хотя в определённых случаях они могут быть равны друг другу (как в вашем случае).

Ну а дальше уже всё легко. В первом случае в `a` лежит список, в котором три раза повторен ОДИН И ТОТ же список. И если вы меняете элемент в нём, то во всех трёх позициях мы видим изменение, потому что это просто три отображения одного и того же списка. Во втором случая через списковое включение у вас создался список из ТРЁХ РАЗНЫХ списков, которые просто имеёт одно и тоже значение на данный момент, но между собой они никак не связаны, и если вы меняете один из них, на остальные это никак не повлияет.